# Javascript filter parent array based on child containing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to filter the parent array `products` based on the selected value which should be contained as the child. For example in my case I was trying to get all the product objects as an array which contained the string "iphone". It is not working for me and I can't seem to locate my error. Please may someone help.

**What I have tried:**

```
    const selected = 'iphone'

const products =  [
     {
      id: "4irnflpd0",
      productItem:  [ "iphone", "ipad", "kindle"],
    },
     {
      id: "glrscb1m3s9k",
      productItem:  ["airpods","iphone",],
    },
     {
      id: "uumkugk3jxof",
      productItem:  ["macbook","cable"]
    },
]

var filtered = products.map(o=>{
    o = Object.assign({},o);   //Clone the object. So any changes will not affect the original array.
    o.productItem.map(p=>{   //Use map to loop thru the products
        p = p.filter(v=>v === selected);  //Filter the products which include selected
    });
    return o;
})
```

**Expected array output:**

```
const products =  [
    {
        id: "4irnflpd0",
        productItem:  [ "iphone", "ipad", "kindle"],
      },
       {
        id: "glrscb1m3s9k",
        productItem:  ["airpods","iphone",],
      },
]
```

Comment: `const filtered = products.filter(p => p.productItem.includes("iphone"))`

Comment: Did you try storing the `o.productItem.map` result back into `o.productItem`? So you would have `o.productItem = o.productItem.map(o=>`

Comment: @Thankyou WOAHHHH That was such a simple way to do it. Thank you so much that worked!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple `filter()` method should work for us in this case. T further simplify, we can also use object restructuring, so instead of writing `product.productItem.includes(selected)`, we'll only need to write `productItem.includes(selected)`.

All we have to do is `filter` the source array by which items include the `selected` value:

```js
const selected = 'iphone';

const products = [
  { id: "4irnflpd0", productItem: ["iphone", "ipad", "kindle"] },
  { id: "glrscb1m3s9k", productItem: ["airpods", "iphone", ] },
  { id: "uumkugk3jxof", productItem: ["macbook", "cable"] },
];

const filtered = products.filter(({productItem}) => productItem.includes(selected));

console.log(filtered);
```

If you'd prefer not to use Object destructuring, just swap that filter line for this more traditional one:

```js
products.filter(p => p.productItem.includes(selected))
```

If you're not sure that every single item in your array will have the `productItem` key, then you should use optional chaining to prevent an error being thrown. This is as simple as adding `?` before after property name. Here it is all put together:

```js
products.filter(p => p.productItem?.includes(selected))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I learnt something new from this . Wow this really helped. Thank you again!!!!!

Comment: @DohanBhagat thanks, I'm glad to hear it! I'm always learning

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` methods on products array and find if the selected item is available in the `productItems`

```js
const selected = 'iphone'
const products =  [
     { id: "4irnflpd0", productItem: [ "iphone", "ipad", "kindle"] },
     { id: "glrscb1m3s9k", productItem: ["airpods","iPhone",] },
     {id: "uumkugk3jxof", productItem: ["macbook","cable"] }
]

var filtered = products.filter(product => 
      product.productItem?.includes(selected));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Use `?.` to be more concise.  `products.filter(product => product.productItem?.includes(selected);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to make a copy since with map function you allocated the result to new variable without changing the new array
So you need to do this

```
const filtered = products.map(p=>{
    return p.productItem.includes(selected)
})
```

Comment: Or just `p => p.productItem.includes(selected)`

Comment: You can get rid of the curly braces altogether and the return statement to make it even more concise: `products.map(p => p.productItem.includes(selected))`